# Getting invalid_grant: AADSTS65001: The user or administrator has not consented to use the application even though it has been consent by the admin

Tags: azure-active-directory

I am trying to access my web api written in .Net Core from a ReactJs client application. I have registered both the application in Azure AD and given Admin Consent to the Web API in ReactJs API Permission section. Even after configuring this I am getting *invalid_grant: AADSTS65001: The user or administrator has not consented to use the application*

Can any please help me regarding this please. How should I connect to the web api.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve the error "***invalid_grant: AADSTS65001: The user or administrator has not consented to use the application***", try the following:

- Make sure to have **Global admin role** and grant admin consent for the below API permissions of your application:

***Go to Azure Portal -> Azure Active Directory -> App Registrations -> Your app -> API permissions -> Add permissions***

[image: image1]

- After granting admin consent, please check whether the status turned green or not.
- Make sure whether the below options are checked or not in your **authentication tab** like below:

[image: image2]

**If still the issue persists, make use of below document if helpful:**

[4 ways to fix error AADSTS65001 (issues with Admin Consent!) - #SharePointProblems / Koskila.net](https://www.koskila.net/how-to-fix-admin-consent-issues-aadsts65001/)